# Longitudinal waves from Maxwell equations

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

It is written in Wikipedia that:

> After Heaviside's attempts to generalize Maxwell's equations, Heaviside concluded that electromagnetic waves were not to be found as longitudinal waves in "free space" or homogeneous media.

[Longitudinal wave - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_wave#Electromagnetics)

However, plasmas can create longitudinal electromagnetic waves. As far as I understand, these waves should be also a solution of Maxwell equations, right? In particular, I guess that if we take Gauss' Law:

$\nabla\cdot\vec{E} = \rho/\epsilon_0$

and Ampere's Law:

$\nabla\times\vec{B} = \mu_0\cdot\vec{J} + \mu_0\epsilon_0\cdot\partial_t\vec{E}$

we could couple them recursively to the Lorentz force to get those longitudinal waves: An initial $\rho$ and $\vec{J}$ defining the fields, the fields updating the position of charges, charges updating the $\rho$, their movement updating $\vec{J}$, and $\rho$ and $\vec{J}$ updating $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ back. If we were looking for longitudinal solutions, we should get $\vec{B} = 0$ and $\nabla\cdot\vec{E} = \partial_xE_x$. However, this solution does not look straightforward to me from the procedure described above (which is the standard algorithm of a PIC code), so I am wondering which initial conditions would lead me to such a result. Any idea?

Comment: Just to clarify: there are no longitudinal EM waves in free space (aka "vacuum"), but in a media (such as plasma) this is possible.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote in the first lines after the quote.